# Rename file by swaping text

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rename

I need to rename files by swaping some text. 
I had for example :

```
CATEGORIE_2017.pdf
CLASSEMENT_2016.pdf
CATEGORIE_2018.pdf
PROPRETE_2015.pdf
...
```

and I want them

```
2017_CATEGORIE.pdf
2016_CLASSEMENT.pdf
2018_CATEGORIE.pdf
2015_PROPRETE.pdf
```

I came up with this bash version :

```
ls *.pdf | while read i
do 
    new_name=$(echo $i |sed -e 's/\(.*\)_\(.*\)\.pdf/\2_\1\.pdf/')
    mv $i $new_name
    echo "---"
done
```

It is efficient but seems quite clumsy to me. Does anyone have a smarter solution, for example with *rename* ?

Comment: doesn't look that clumsy to me

Comment: [Don't use `ls` for this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You simply mean `for i in *.pdf` and also [fix your quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).  You might want to consult with http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rename` you can do the renaming like this:

```
rename -n 's/([^_]+)_([^.]+).pdf/$2_$1.pdf/g' *.pdf
```

The option `-n` does nothing, it just prints what would happen. If you are satisfied, remove the `-n` option.

I use `[^_]+` and `[^.]+` to capture the part of the filename before and after the the `_`. The syntax `[^_]` means everything but a `_`.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
ls *.pdf | awk -F"[_.]" '{print "mv "$0" "$2"_"$1"."$3}' | sh
```

Using awk, swap the positions and form the mv command and pass it to shell.

Comment: In the general case, this is dangerous. If you have complete confidence that all your file names are trivial, this is fine for private use; but at least the answer should point out the caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `bash`:

```
for file in *_*.pdf; do
    no_ext=${file%.*}
    new_name=${no_ext##*_}_${no_ext%_*}.${file##*.}
    mv -- "$file" "$new_name"
done
```